# How to scaffold views from controller separately

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm wondering if Visual Studio 2013 has any way to scaffold views using the controllers in MVC. I want to use a repository pattern, so for now I created that myself, and I would like to generate the views.

In Visual Studio 2012 I used the technique explained [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) by Scott Hanselman, but with the new scaffolding introduced in the new version of Visual Studio I was wondering if this is not supported natively

Answer (score 0):

The scaffolding functionality appears to be embedded in Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Mvc.5.0.dll and I can't find any way to customize it further. So if there isn't a built-in means of scaffolding the way their used to be, it looks like you're doing to have to roll your own mechanism.